# Cannot add items to a QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I have a program that queries a SQLite database and displays some of the information from this database in a table.  I've done this a few times in the program, and sorted out a more ambiguous way to do it, so I wrote up a new functions, but it always throws an assertion:

```
ASSERT failure in QList<T>::operator[]: "index out of range", file /usr/include/qt/QtCore/qlist.h, line 462
```

Here is my code:

```
void Sync::on_btnLoadTable_clicked()
{
if ( !m_district ) return;

ui->tblTableView->clear();
ui->tblTableView->setRowCount( 0 );
ui->tblTableView->setColumnCount( 0 );

ui->tblTableView->setSortingEnabled( false );

QStringList fields;
QList< QStringList > rows = m_district->getAllOf( ui->cboTables->currentText(), &fields );

int rowCount = rows.size();
if ( rowCount > 0 )
{
    int columns = fields.size();
    ui->tblTableView->setColumnCount( columns );
    for(int c=0; c < columns; c++)
        ui->tblTableView->setHorizontalHeaderItem( c, new QTableWidgetItem(fields[c]) );

    ui->tblTableView->setRowCount( rowCount );
    for(int r=0; r < rowCount; r++)
    {
        int cols = rows[r].size();
        qDebug() << "Fields=" << columns << ", row columns=" << cols;
        qDebug() << "Table is " << ui->tblTableView->columnCount() << "x" << ui->tblTableView->rowCount();
        for(int c=0; c < columns; c++)
        {
            qDebug() << "row column count=" << rows[r].size();
            qDebug() << "row=" << r << ",col=" << c;
            QString data = rows[r][c];
            qDebug() << "text=" << data;
            QTableWidgetItem *item = new QTableWidgetItem( data );
            ui->tblTableView->setItem( r, c, item );
            qDebug() << "inserted [" << r << "," << c << "]";
        }
    }
    qDebug() << "Finished";
}
ui->tblTableView->setSortingEnabled( true );

}
```

And it outputs the following in qDebug:

```
Fields= 10 , row columns= 10 
Table is  10 x 6381
row column count= 10 
row= 0 ,col= 0 
text= "137288735238a076b1ed644781a8cdf3f598067b41" 
ASSERT failure in QList<T>::operator[]: "index out of range", file /usr/include/qt/QtCore/qlist.h, line 462
```

I put up a series of breakpoints, and it appears that it breaks on the `ui->tblTableView->setItem( r, c, item );` line, but the column and row count seem to imply that row `r` and column `c` are both valid places to put an item.

Any ideas why it would be giving me this assertion?

Comment: The code seems to be fine. Please post the stacktrace of the failure.

Comment: I agree, your calls to the table widget seem fine.

Comment: So, I didn't realize that cells got a change signal if I am updating them via code (I thought it was only used for when a cell is editted at runtime).  I added a flag so the change code wouldn't be triggered if I were populating the table, and that has fixed it.  Thanks for the stacktrace suggestion @Riateche, I hadn't noticed it in the views before.